# Alarm circuit for 4 to 7Hz

Tags: microcontroller

Alarm circuit for 4 to 7Hz. i have require a circuit that gives alarm when 4 to 7Hz signal is applied on its input only and not produce alarm on other frequency range signal

Comment: Is this for a theta wave sensor?

Answer (score 1):

The desired result can be achieved through analog filters, or digital / DSP filters. As the desired sharpness Q of cut-off beyond the frequency range of interest is not specified, assumption is that a very sharp cut-off is desirable. This is in line with various documents on the web discussing 4-7 Hz brain Theta Wave detection, which mention very sharp desired cut-off.

The mechanism in either case is the same:

- Option 1: Signal --> 4 Hz High-pass filter --> 7 Hz low-pass filter --> peak detector --> comparator --> alarm
- Option 2: Signal --> single-pole Band-pass filter --> peak detector --> comparator --> Alarm

While a single band-pass filter is simpler to implement, this would typically not provide the kind of flat response in the pass band that seems to be desired for theta wave detectors.

---

**Analog Filters:**

- High component count, increasing with desired Q. For an arbitrarily sharp cut-off i.e. brick-wall filter, an arbitrarily order filter would be required.
- Use a filter design program such as [Texas Instruments FilterPro](http://www.ti.com/tool/filterpro) (free) to simulate desired filter profile and determine filter order, component values and topology of choice
- Given the brevity of the question, locating and adapting a schematic  from web searches for a *peak detector followed by a comparator* is left as an exercise to the OP.

**Digital Filters:**

- A suitable DSP could be used to capture the signal using its ADC and implement a Finite Impulse Response (FIR) brick-wall band-pass filter or pair of sinc filters. The trade-off in this case is roll-off sharpness versus signal delay: An arbitrarily perfect rectangular band-pass behavior has infinite delay.
- Alternatively, an IIR band-pass filter (gentler roll-off at corner frequencies) can be implemented.
- This would be followed by signal presence detection (a digital implementation of the peak detector + comparator above), to drive the alarm via a GPIO pin.
- If a DSP is undesirable, similar filtering can be done by coding IIR or FIR filters on a sufficiently capable microcontroller: For instance, the Texas Instruments Stellaris microcontrollers (ARM) have code available for implementing such IIR and FIR filters.